# How do I create a subquery linking to 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, where-clause

Basically, I need to create a subquery that filters a movie database records. I need to retrieve movies that are spoken in Japanese ('ja') and have the genre('action'). Each time I run the code below I end up getting results with movies that are spoken in Japanese and are action movies. But I also get movies that are not spoken in Japanese but are action movies. How do I solve this?  Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT id, title, vote_average FROM Movie
WHERE id IN
(SELECT id FROM HasGenre WHERE genre_id=
    (SELECT genre_id FROM Genre WHERE genre='Action')
)
AND id IN
    (SELECT id FROM HasSpokenLanugage WHERE spoken_language_iso_code='ja')
ORDER BY vote_average DESC;
```

Movie table:

Movie_ID | Title 
1        | Start wars 
2 | Halo

Genre table:

Genre_ID  | Genre 
1         | Horror
2         | Action

HasGenre table:

Movie_ID| Genre_ID 
1| Horror  
2| Action

Spoken_language table:

Movie_ID  | Spoken_language_iso_code 
1         | 'ja'  
2         | 'en'

Comment: Can you provide the schema and some example data to help demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @Jawi I have added some example data hopefully that helps

Comment: @Jawi also, ID is the ID of the movie

Comment: HINT: `AND` is used to satisfy both condition.  `OR` on the other hand is used to satisfy either one.

Comment: @Eric So how do I get around this? I only want to retrieve action movies that are spoken in Japanese. By using AND/OR I get all Japanese spoken action movies as well as other language spoken action movies?

Comment: I don't see any relationship between the tables.

Comment: @Eric Check now. I think I have cleared the issue up. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple `JOIN` to get the result.

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, m.vote_average
FROM Movie m
JOIN HasGenre hg ON hg.id = m.id
JOIN Genre g ON g.genre_id = hg.genre_id
JOIN HasSpokenLanugage hsl ON hsl.id = m.id
WHERE g.genre = 'Action' AND hsl.spoken_language_iso_code = 'ja'
ORDER BY vote_average DESC;
```

If you have to use subquery, you can use `EXIST`

```
SELECT id, title, vote_average 
FROM Movie m
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM HasGenre WHERE genre_id = (
        SELECT genre_id FROM Genre WHERE genre='Action'
    ) AND id = m.id
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM HasSpokenLanugage 
    WHERE spoken_language_iso_code='ja' AND id = m.id
);
```

Comment: there appears to be a closing parenthesis error in the second one? Not sure where to go from here. MySQL knowledge is limited haha

Comment: I don't see any missing parenthesis.  What's the exact error?

Comment: says "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = m.id ) AND EXISTS (     SELECT 1     FROM HasSpokenLanugage      WHER' at line 8"